# Nested Select query in Insert using Parameters

Tags: sql-server, parameters, nested, procedure

I have these tables: Students, Courses, Grades and Faculties.

I would like to create a stored procedure to insert in table Grades(Grade_ID,Course_ID,Student_ID,Value):
- the ID of a given Course
- the ID of Students who are enrolled at a specific Faculty.

This is what i have for now, and it's not working:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spTable
@Faculty_ID int,
@Course_ID int
AS
INSERT INTO Note (Course_ID,Student_ID)
(@Course_ID,(SELECT  s.Student_ID
FROM   Studenti AS s
WHERE s.Faculty_ID=@Faculty_ID));
RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the `INSERT` statement is wrong. You need to read documentation thoroughly.

```
INSERT INTO Note (Course_ID,Student_ID)
SELECT @Course_ID, s.Student_ID
FROM   Studenti AS s
WHERE s.Faculty_ID=@Faculty_ID
```